# undefined is not an object while evaluating props in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

So i am passing some data to the page where i am navigating on click event as

```js
render(){
     const goToPageTwo = () => Actions.gray({text:"hello"});
return(
    </View>
    <Button onPress={goToPageTwo} title="Checkout" color="#841584"/>
      </View>
);
}
```

Now in my other component if i access it as props

```js
this.props.text
```

It gives an exception saying props is undefined

Please guide how to resolve
Thanks!

**Update:**

Code which is accessing this.props

```js
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'; // New code
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Alert,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const GrayScreen = () => {


  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome} onPress={() => Actions.black()}>{this.props.text}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'blue',
  },
});

export default GrayScreen;
```

code for Routing compponent

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import Archives from './components/Archives.js';
import ScarletScreen from './components/ScarletScreen.js';
import GrayScreen from './components/GrayScreen.js';
import Zaika from './components/Zaika.js';

    import {Table, TableWrapper, Row, Rows, Col, Cols, Cell } from 'react-native-table-component';
    import {
       Alert,Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,TextInput,Keyboard
    } from 'react-native';
    import NavBar, { NavGroup, NavButton, NavButtonText, NavTitle } from 'react-native-nav';
    import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
    import App1 from './App1.js';


    const instructions = Platform.select({
      ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
        'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
      android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
        'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
    });

    export default class App extends Component<{}> {



      render() {



        return (

             <Router>
          <Scene key="root">
                  <Scene
          key="zaika"
              component={Zaika}
              title="Delhi zaika"
              initial
            />
                 <Scene key="app1"
              component={App1}
              title="app1"

            />
            <Scene key="scarlet"
              component={ScarletScreen}
              title="Scarlet"

            />
            <Scene {...this.props}  
              key="gray"
              component={GrayScreen}
              title="Gray"

            />

          </Scene>


        </Router>


        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
      },
      instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
      },
        head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
      text: { marginLeft: 5 },
      row: { height: 30 }
    });
```

Comment: I think you're probably going to need to provide more context than this. The code at the point where you attempt to access `this.props.text` in the other component would be a good start.

Comment: do  i need to add props in scene as well?

Comment: Nope, that was enough for Val to provide the correct answer (below) :)

Comment: @RichChurcher Thank you for asking the first question for me to possibly provide an answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't have instance property `props` with [React Stateless Functional Component](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwis_8XdyZrYAhWEmpQKHeJhCmIQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhackernoon.com%2Freact-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc&usg=AOvVaw0e94BXMFhtYgmPr8X1Z7J1).

The `props` will pass in as first argument instead:

```js
const GrayScreen = (props) => {    
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome} onPress={() => Actions.black()}>{props.text}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: such a silly mistake.i forgot it is not a class thanks @Val:)

Comment: If I was being super-picky, I'd suggest pointing out in the answer that `this` is not *meaningless* in a stateless functional component: it just doesn't have a `props` property on it. Because it's also an arrow function, `this` will depend on the enclosing context.